# AJAX created SELECT "invisible" inside FORM data

Tags: ajax, forms, select, post, dynamic

I'm new here but I found many help in the passt reading Q&A.

My problem is this:
in a HTML page I have a form with many fields, one of these is a SELECT with name and id "f_container"; I pose it inside a  element (`<div id=f_cont_ins></div>`) ad use an AJAX function to populate it dynamically.

```
function ele_con(id,cod_cont) {
    var http = createRequestObject();
    http.open('get', 'fler.php?id='+id+'&art='+document.getElementById('stp').value);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4){
        var response = http.responseText;
            document.getElementById('f_cont_ins').innerHTML = response;
            }
        }
    http.send(null);
}
```

The "response" is right formatted an display right in the browser (Firefox); if I inspect the element or analyze the DOM structure it seems all ok, and I can get the value of a selection with `document.getElementById('f_container').value`.

But when I post the form, the field "f_cointainer" isn't present in the `print_r($_POST);` array, but all the other yes.

I navigate the net but don't found a clear ansver that these is not possible or a workaround to solve the problem.

I have an idea that is to use the `document.location='page.php?par1=a&par2=b&f_container=5';` created reading value with document.getElementById, but I prefer a POST solution if it exist.

Comment: Is the select actually _inside_ of the form you are trying to send, or do you maybe have placed it outside by accident?

Comment: do you post the form with ajax?

Comment: @CBroe -> The FORM is inside: if I generate it with php at load time and POST without changes, it is visible in the $_POST array; if I update it with ajax, it disappears.

Comment: @claustrofob -> the form has the submit input field.

Comment: NOTE: the page is inside an iframe, but I don't think these is a problem.

Comment: @mYmage +1 nobody has never had problems with iframes.